# Understanding the loading process of SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, owin

I am trying to learn and setup a SignalR solution which will be of a certain scale (~1500 concurrent users) and I want to make sure I fully understand how it works behind the scenes.

In particular, I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how the following setup actually initiates SignalR

(taken from)

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that the code uses an `assembly` annotation, for Owin, and it specifies the class to fire up as well.

But I am struggling with is how this actually works.

When does the OWIN dll actually load, and when does the `Startup` class actually get loaded?

Why is OWIN needed for SignalR at all? Is it just a convenience usage library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good reference to how this works on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection).

> Every OWIN Application has a startup class where you specify components for the application pipeline. There are different ways you can connect your startup class with the runtime, depending on the hosting model you choose (OwinHost, IIS, and IIS-Express).

Basically, SignalR is an OWIN (The Open Web Interface for .NET) Middleware.

from [getting started with OWIN and Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana):

> Open Web Interface for .NET (OWIN) defines an abstraction between .NET web servers and web applications. By decoupling the web server from the application, OWIN makes it easier to create middleware for .NET web development. Also, OWIN makes it easier to port web applications to other hosts—for example, self-hosting in a Windows service or other process.

During the App startup, Katana searches for startup classes to bootstrap each of the middleware components into the app.  You can consider any startup class you create to be processed in the same way a traditional bootstrapped object might be initialized from `global.asax`, `app.run`, `void main`, or others, without being bound to the context of these methodologies.

**edit**

The question of the javascript file `/signalR/hubs` is quite complex, but has a fair amount of [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy).  Essentially, the reference is to a **dynamically** generated proxy.

> When you write code to call server methods, the generated proxy enables you to use syntax that looks as though you were executing a local function: you can write serverMethod(arg1, arg2) instead of invoke('serverMethod', arg1, arg2). The generated proxy syntax also enables an immediate and intelligible client-side error if you mistype a server method name. And if you manually create the file that defines the proxies, you can also get IntelliSense support for writing code that calls server methods.

The problem is that Sitecore and other CMS utilities will actually try to handle the URL pattern in their routes instead of allowing the proxy to take action.  You will want to make sure that your CMS has an ignore specified for the SignalR bits.

In the web.config, update your IgnoreUrlPrefixes:

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes"
    value="/sitecore/default.aspx|/trace.axd|
     .....
    |/signalr|/signalr/hubs" />
```

Comment: Ok so correct me if I am wrong, but the OWIN standard abstracts away the fact that I am indeed using IIS, but I COULD use anything else and the code wouldn't change?

Comment: I think another area I was confused was that the `app.MapSignalR()` method is an extension method, not on the `IAppBuilder` interface, so it looked like SignalR was baked into OWIN

Comment: Yes, you could use other hosts that support the Katana process and not change the implementation of your middleware.  also, yes, the `IAppBuilder` interface is confusing at first.

Comment: Just as an additional question, the request to the `/signalR/hubs` file, what exactly serves that? Is that handled by the `app.MapSignalR()` which takes care of it? Reason I ask is that I am trying to install SignalR into a CMS (sitecore) which seems to be ignoring the call altogether and returning a 404

Comment: the /signalR/hubs is quite a concept in itself, so I'll edit the answer with a bit more info but it might be worth it's own question.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I had already added it to that setting actually and I get a 404 as opposed to a sitecore error, but my issue 'seems' to be that the call to the Katana startup class never gets called, I have attached a break point to the class but it never breaks, however, on a standalone asp.net project (the sample that comes from the signalr doco) it works every time, I just cannot seem to get the proxy generated

Comment: I have actually just solved it, I was not copying over the OWIN DLLs into the BIN directory of my sitecore site (simple mistake), now it all works fine, thanks Andrew Counts